# Combining DOM-events in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a webpage with pseudo-canvas (see https://jsfiddle.net/memeladon/vff01jq6/). Circles randomly change their color when a user hovers a cursor over them (mouseover event). How can I modify a program so that colors change only when both left mouse is clicked and a cursor is over a circle (click + mouseover events)? Currently I create cells with such a function:

```
function createCell() {
    var new_cell = document.createElement("DIV"),
        cell_circle = document.createElement("DIV");
    new_cell.classList.add("paint-cell");
    cell_circle.classList.add("paint-cell__circle");
    new_cell.appendChild(cell_circle);
    new_cell.addEventListener("mouseover",  function () { changeColor(cell_circle); });
    return new_cell;
}
```

Comment: Change *mouseover* to *click* . if it is *clicked*, mouseover is always true ;)

Comment: I want to be able to color several circles with a single "swipe", like in Windows Paint. If I change to _click_, then only one circle can be colored at a time.

Comment: I know in jQuery you can add custom events and throw them dynamically. The same is probably possible in pure JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mouse event object in your callback function and see if a mouse button is clicked

```
new_cell.addEventListener("mouseover",  function (e) { 
   if(e.buttons !== 0)
   {
     //do cool stuff
   }
});
```